# Why does my code produce a runtime error?

Tags: python, arcmap, error

My code produces a runtime error and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
... import arcpy
... from arcpy import env
... from arcpy.sa import *
... 
... #set the workspace environment
... env.workspace = "directory"
... 
... class Raster:
...     def __init__(self, inRast):
...         self.inRast = inRast
... 
...     value = "Value"
...     #create a variable which will store the remap (this will be the same for all rasters)
...     remap = RemapRange([[0, 3.99, 1], [4, 9.99, 2], [10, 15.99, 3], [16, 30.99, 4], [31, 60.99, 5], [61, 789.548, 6]])
...     
... #Create an object of the Raster class
... rast_obj1 = Raster("Slope_tif7")
... 
... #Create array to store rasters
... rast_arr = []
... 
... #Append the object(s) to the empty array
... rast_arr.append(rast_obj1)
... 
... #Create function to 
... def changeRange(obj):
...     #Call the Reclassify function and store it in a variable
...     reclassed = Reclassify(obj.inRast, obj.value, obj.remap)
...     #Save the output
...     reclassed.save("directory")
... 
... #Loop through the array to change all of their values 
... for obj in rast_arr:
...     changeRange(obj)
```

Error:

> Runtime error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 35, in 
> File "", line 31, in changeRange
> RuntimeError: Invalid pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not explained how you run this code, within ArcMap or an IDE? It also seems that you have obfuscated the code by not showing the path, unless you really have just typed "directory" in and if that's the case then that's your problem. You don't use best practise and check in/out the extension license and personally I would not have created a Class called Raster when such a class exists in Python, its very confusing as to what it really is. With all that said I took you code put in proper paths and a file name and everything ran without error, see the additions below:

```py
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

#set the workspace environment
env.workspace = r"c:\scratch"

class Raster:
    def __init__(self, inRast):
        self.inRast = inRast

    value = "Value"
    #create a variable which will store the remap (this will be the same for all rasters)
    remap = RemapRange([[0, 3.99, 1], [4, 9.99, 2], [10, 15.99, 3], [16, 30.99, 4], [31, 60.99, 5], [61, 789.548, 6]])

#Create an object of the Raster class
rast_obj1 = Raster("Slope_tif7.tif")

#Create array to store rasters
rast_arr = []

#Append the object(s) to the empty array
rast_arr.append(rast_obj1)

#Create function to
def changeRange(obj):
    #Call the Reclassify function and store it in a variable
    reclassed = Reclassify(obj.inRast, obj.value, obj.remap)
    #Save the output
    reclassed.save(r"c:\scratch\reclassified.tif")

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")
#Loop through the array to change all of their values
for obj in rast_arr:
    changeRange(obj)
arcpy.CheckInExtension("spatial")
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was missing the ".tif" extension in the directory path as well as in the parameter of the object created.